# Not getting all leads from Meta/Facebook using webhook for page leadgens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

We have integrated leadgen for page using webhook and everything is working great. We are getting leads for all form under that page from facebook.

But after running for few days we have observed an issue, it seems our webhook endpoint is not getting all the leads. There is some difference in lead count between leads we received using webhook and when we check on [Meta Ads Manager](https://adsmanager.facebook.com/adsmanage).

We have check everything on our end and everything seems fine, we even tracked those leads which we didn't receive via webhook and then called our webhook endpoint using impersonated data(simulating body as received from facebook) using those leads and this time it worked.